# how to set AWS IVS Player to normal latency

Tags: html, amazon-ivs

According to Amazon IVS doucumentation,

> Chrome for iOS, Safari for iOS:
> Ultra-low latency playback is not supported. Normal latency playback
> is supported.

So my streams' latency are around 2~5s,but Safari are always delay >15s.
I'm using pure web player to stream:
 `<script src="https://player.live-video.net/1.14.0/amazon-ivs-player.min.js">`

In my scenario, although latency is important, but the simultaneousness is much more crucial than latency.Is there any way to force all the platforms to delay >15s?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a channel, you can choose `NORMAL` latency mode instead of `LOW` ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-channel.html#getting-started-create-channel-cli-no-recording)). Most third-party broadcasting software also has an option to introduce intentional delay, if that's what you're looking to do. Example for OBS [here](https://www.streamscheme.com/how-to-set-up-a-twitch-delay/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Set%20Up%20Stream%20Delay%20in%20OBS%20Studios&text=From%20the%20File%20menu%2C%20select,of%20the%20pop%2Dup%20menu.&text=Locate%20the%20%E2%80%9CStream%20Delay%E2%80%9D%20section,your%20viewers%20see%20your%20broadcast.).

Edit: You can also turn live low latency off in the player (except on iOS). [Docs](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.16.0/web/interfaces/player.html#setlivelowlatencyenabled).